# Не отправляется форма HTML+PHP

Tags: php, html, форма

Никак не могу разобраться в проблеме отправки формы: нажимаю Save и не отправляется.

```html
<main>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php?action=<?=$_GET['action']?>&id=<?=$_GET['id']?>" >
    <label> Имя заказчика <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="<?=$article['customer_name']?>">                       </label>
    <label> Фрахт № <input type="text" name="freight" value="<?=$article['freight']?>">                                         </label>
    <label> Наименование груза <input type="text" name="cargo_name" value="<?=$article['cargo_name']?>">                        </label>
    <label> Планируемая стоимость груза <input type="text" name="estimated_cost" value="<?=$article['estimated_cost']?>">       </label>
    <label>Планируемый вес груза <input type="text" name="planned_cargo_weight" value="<?=$article['planned_cargo_weight']?>">  </label>

    <label> Дата загрузки <input type="date" name="upload_date" value="<?=$article['upload_date']?>">                  </label>
    <label> Дата выгрузки <input type="date" name="unload_date" value="<?=$article['unload_date']?>">                  </label>
    <label> Город загрузки <input type="text" name="download_city" value="<?=$article['download_city']?>">             </label>
    <label> Город выгрузки <input type="text" name="unload_city" value="<?=$article['unload_city']?>">                 </label>
    <label> Адрес загрузки <input type="text" name="download_address" value="<?=$article['download_address']?>">       </label>
    <label> Адрес выгрузки <input type="text" name="unload_address" value="<?=$article['unload_address']?>">           </label>

    <label> Назначенный автотранспорт <input type="text" name="designated_transport" value="<?=$article['designated_transport']?>">            </label>
    <label> Назначенный экспедитор <input type="text" name="designated_forwarder" value="<?=$article['designated_forwarder']?>">                </label>
    <label> Доверенность <input type="text" name="proxy" value="<?=$article['proxy']?>">                                                        </label>
    <label> Стоимость услуг экспедитора <input type="text" name="forwarder_services_costs" value="<?=$article['forwarder_services_costs']?>">   </label>

    <label> Статус выполнения фрахта <input type="text" name="status" value="<?=$article['status']?>">                                  </label>
    <label> Признак поступивших документов <input type="text" name="received_documents" value="<?=$article['received_documents']?>">    </label>
    <label> Примечание к фрахту <input type="text" name="note" value="<?=$article['note']?>">                                           </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
    <!-- <input type=submit" value="Сохранить"> -->
</form>
</main>
```

Обработчик(index.php)

```
if (isset($_GET['action']))
    $action = $_GET['action'];
else
    $action ="";

if ($action == "add"){  //Создать новый фрахт
    if (!empty($_POST)){
        article_new($link, 
            $_POST['customer_name'],
            $_POST['freight'], 
            $_POST['cargo_name'],
            $_POST['estimated_cost'],
            $_POST['planned_cargo_weight'],

            $_POST['upload_date'],
            $_POST['unload_date'],
            $_POST['download_city'],
            $_POST['unload_city'],
            $_POST['download_address'],
            $_POST['unload_address'],

            $_POST['designated_transport'],
            $_POST['designated_forwarder'],
            $_POST['proxy'],
            $_POST['forwarder_services_costs'],

            $_POST['status'],
            $_POST['received_documents'],
            $_POST['note']
        );
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    include("views/form.php");    
}
```

Comment: Вы отправляете post запрос а проверяете get параметр

Comment: не, там все правильно - так и должно быть

Comment: При создании другого сайта с тем же кодом все работает. В этом почему-то нет

Comment: Консоль без ошибок?

Comment: Консоль выдает это: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Хотя статья(а там в бд добавляется статьи) сохранилась и отобразилась в админке

Answer (score 0):

Я немного изменил ваш код, сменив все GET на POST, и все работало: данные отправились.
[image: Заполненная форма]

[image: Результат функции print_r($_POST)]

Comment: Данные может и отправляются, если отправлять сразу же из формы.

Comment: Данные может и отправляются, если отправлять сразу же из формы. Но если поменять все GET на POST, то я не могу из админки перейти в форму отправки.